# Regular Expression - Find a string and eliminate until certain character

Tags: php, regex

PHP: I have this string: 1_1234567890, 2_1234567890, 3_1234567890 … I need a regular expression able to find if there is "2_" and if positive, remove 2_ and the characters after until the next commas, in this case remove "2_123456789,". So my output, must be: 1_1234567890, 3_1234567890.

Comment: PHP, or `NSregularexpression` ?? Don't include two contradicting tags...

Comment: PHP. But a friend gave me a solution: preg_replace('/(2_[^,]*+,)/', '', $string); - Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace('|(2_.+?, ?)|', '', $string);
```

Comment: This assumes trailing comma and space in `$string`.

Comment: Which is what he requested

Answer (score 1):

With PHP:

```
$result = preg_replace('~\b2_[^,]*(?:,\h*|\h*$)~', '', $str);
```